# Login by Google OpenID fails in FF 4.0.1 with an HTTP 403 error

Tags: support, firefox, internet-explorer, 403-forbidden

I cannot log in to `StackExchange.com` or `Cooking.StackExchange.com`.

I tried Cooking first, using this URL:

https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?st=mtiB2tjDvVF7_xptMKkQ&from_login=1&hl=en-US&pli=1

When I clicked "Allow," I got

> HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden You do not have permission to access the document or program you requested.

So I tried `StackExchange.com` and had the same problem.

**UPDATE**
I just tried StackExchange again using IE7 instead Firefox and it worked. FF fail?  I have v4.0.1.

Comment: Try to clear cookies in FF. Maybe they were rotten.

Comment: @Chichiray - I cleared my cookies and now I can't even login to meta-stack using FF >.X...programmers is broke too.  All my stacklogins are busted.  suweet...

Comment: After searching through some related questions I see I can email team@stackoverflow.com regarding the issue.  So I shall...

Comment: Gee, I am so sorry. How do other browsers like FF3, Chrome and Safari behave? You can of course send the mail. Don't forget to mention that you already posted a Q on meta (this one :) ).

Comment: Jeff on the SO team at team@stackoverflow.com told me to disable all my browser add-ons.  This resolved the issue.  I don't know which add-on caused it, but the ones I want to keep don't affect it so I'm good to go.

Comment: Can someone tell us what generates this? I have this on Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the OP, this problem was caused by an unspecified Firefox add-on, and is resolved.

Please upvote this answer to get this question off the "unanswered" list.

Comment: I have the same problem with Chrome, it happens quite often and is very annoying. How can we find the real cause?

Comment: @SorinSbarnea nobody is ever going to see your comment to this old, obscure post. (I only saw it because I got a notification about a comment on a post I wrote.) If you're still having this issue, you're better off posting a brand-new question and linking to this one.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and disabled my Firefox Add-ons one by one to find it was Vimperator.

This was FF 19.0 on Ubuntu with Vimperator 3.7.